# What is x[:,:,::-1] in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, image-processing

```
import numpy as np 
import cv2 as cv
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
img=cv.imread("content.jpg")
x=np.array(img,dtype=np.uint8)
y=x[:,:,::-1]
plt.imshow(x,interpolation='nearest')
plt.show()
plt.imshow(y,interpolation='nearest')
plt.show()
```

I have some doubts regarding this code

1. What `y=x[:,:,::-1]` doing in this code.
2. The plot of image x is different from the original image, why is it so?
3. The plot of image
   y is same as the original image, what is the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cv2` reads image as `BGR`, that is, the pixels are in `BGR` order. On the other hand `plt.imshow()` uses the more common `RBG` settings.

`x[:,:,::-1]` essentially inverts the order of color, so `BGR` becomes `RGB`.

So the command

```
y = x[:,:,::-1]
```

is equivalent to `cv2.cvtColor`:

```
y = cv2.cvtColor(x, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
```

Comment: @cgDude No, that's just how OpenCV is designed. You can use other packages, e.g. [plt.imread](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imread.html) to read images as `RGB`.

Comment: can you tell me what ```::``` this does here. I know that```: ``` is used to get all the values in a particular dimension

Comment: It's short hand for `start:end:step`. similar to what you would put in `range`.